# Converting Javascript object to Javascript array

Tags: javascript, json, knockout.js

I am using a knockout observable array to populate a dropdownlist.The dropdownlist gets populated if I hardcode the array values.But I am now trying to get the data from the database.I am using JSON format for the javascript object.I am accessing a single property of the javascript object i.e; Certification and I am creating an array which I am passing back to a script.But each time the value that is passed back is undefined whereas the array shows up in the console.

The code to convert to an array that I am using is

```
var getCertifications = function () {
    $.ajax({
    type : "GET",
    async : false,
    url : "/Provider/GetCertifications",
    dataType : "json",
    success: function (data) {
        var arrCertification = [];
        $.each(data, function (i, item) {
            arrCertification.push((item.Certification));
        });
        return arrCertification;
    },
    error : function () {
        alert(" An error occurred.");
        }
     });
 };
```

The code for the knockout observables is

```
  var certificates = getCertifications();
  self.certificationArray = ko.observableArray(certificates);
```

and the HTML is

```
 <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-sm-2 control-label labelfont">Certification:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <select class="form-control" id="certification" name="certification" data-bind="value: certification, options: certificationArray, optionsCaption: 'Select a Certification'">
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Could some one please guide me on where I am going wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The getCertifications() function doesn't return anything.  All it does is kick off an ajax call.

You need to use some sort of call back or promise object to get the results of this call.  Using a callback this would look something like:

```
var getCertifications = function (cb) {
    $.ajax({
    type : "GET",
    async : false,
    url : "/Provider/GetCertifications",
    dataType : "json",
    success: function (data) {
        var arrCertification = [];
        $.each(data, function (i, item) {
            arrCertification.push((item.Certification));
        });
        cb(arrCertification);
    },
    error : function () {
        alert(" An error occurred.");
        }
     });
 };

 getCertifications(function(certificates) {
     self.certificationArray = ko.observableArray(certificates);
 });
```

A better pattern would be to use promises.  The $.ajax method returns a promise.  However the callback approach is a good place to start in order to get an understanding of handling asynchronous code.

Comment: Doesn't the return in the success part fire.Sorry if this is a noob question.New to Ajax and Jquery.

Comment: No that isn't doing anything.  Control has already left the function by this point.  The AJAX call is asynchronous, so the success gets called sometime later once the server returns the result.

Comment: Doesn't async : false make it synchronous.

Comment: No. You can't make it synchronous.  An HTTP call is asynchronous, and nothing you do on the client can change that.  the async property in $.ajax is badly named.  It's about making sure that if you raise multiple async events in a page they will all fire/return in the same order you raised them.  Specifically it doesn't fire an ajax request until all previous requests have been completed.

Comment: Thanks for the explaination as well.Appreciate it.